# Problems after adding a stamina system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've added a stamina system in my game, but when I try do call the function there's a few problems happening:
I can't jump when my character is sprinting and when I jump and press the sprint button my character doesn't fall anymore, he basically just flies.

```
PlayerController
```

```
private Vector3 playerVelocity;
private bool groundedPlayer;

private CharacterController controller;
private PlayerControls playerControls;
private InputManager inputManager;
public HealthBar healthBar;
public StaminaBar staminaBar;

public int currentHealth;
public int maxHealth = 100;
public int currentStamina;
public int maxStamina = 100;
public int staminaDrain = 10;

[SerializeField]
private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
[SerializeField]
private float playerRunSpeed= 1f;
[SerializeField]
private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
[SerializeField]
private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

private Transform cameraTransform;

private void Start()
{  
    currentHealth = maxHealth;
    healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    currentStamina = maxStamina;
    staminaBar.SetMaxStamina(maxStamina);
    
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    inputManager = InputManager.Instance;
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
    //player = GameObject.Find("Player");
}


void Update()
{
    groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    }

    Vector2 movement = inputManager.GetPlayerMovement();
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(movement.x, 0f, movement.y);
    move = cameraTransform.forward * move.z + cameraTransform.right * move.x;
    move.y = 0f;
    //controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);
    
    if(inputManager.isRunning && currentStamina > 0)
    {
        controller.Move(move * playerRunSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        staminaBar.UseStamina(staminaDrain);
        staminaBar.staminaSlider.value = currentStamina;
    }
    else
    {
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);
    }

    

    // Changes the height position of the player..

    if (inputManager.PlayerJumpedThisFrame() && groundedPlayer)
    {
        playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

StaminaBar script

```
public class StaminaBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider staminaSlider;
    private PlayerController playerController;
    
    
    private WaitForSeconds regenTick = new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    private Coroutine regen;

    public void SetMaxStamina(int stamina){
        staminaSlider.maxValue = stamina;
        staminaSlider.value = stamina;

    }
    public void SetStamina(int stamina){
        staminaSlider.value = stamina;
    }

    public void UseStamina(int amount){
        if(playerController.currentStamina - amount >= 0){
            playerController.currentStamina -= amount;
            staminaSlider.value = playerController.currentStamina;
            Debug.Log("Losing Stamina");
            if(regen != null)
                StopCoroutine(regen);

            regen = StartCoroutine(RegenStamina());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("NotEnoughStamina");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator RegenStamina()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);


        while(playerController.currentStamina < playerController.maxStamina){
            playerController.currentStamina += playerController.maxStamina/100;
            staminaSlider.value = playerController.currentStamina;
            yield return regenTick;
        }
        regen = null;
    }
}
```

Input Manager

```
{
    private StaminaBar staminaBar;
    private PlayerController playerController;
    [SerializeField]
    private float bulletHitMissDistance = 25f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform bulletParent;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform barrelTransform;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject bulletPrefab;

    [SerializeField]
    private float damage = 100;
    public float impactForce = 30;
    public float fireRate = 8f;
    WaitForSeconds rapidFireWait;

    public bool isRunning;
 

    private static InputManager _instance;
    public static InputManager Instance 
    {
        get {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

   private PlayerControls playerControls;
   private Transform cameraTransform;
   Coroutine fireCoroutine;


   private void Awake()
   {  
        if(_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else 
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
        playerControls = new PlayerControls();
        //Cursor.visible = false;


        rapidFireWait = new WaitForSeconds(1/fireRate);
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

        
        playerControls.Player.RunStart.performed += x => Running();
        playerControls.Player.RunEnd.performed += x => RunningStop();
        playerControls.Player.Shoot.started += _ => StartFiring();
        playerControls.Player.Shoot.canceled += _ => StopFiring();
   }


   private void  OnEnable()
   {
    playerControls.Enable();
    //playerControls.Player.Shoot.performed += _ => StartFiring();
   }

   private void OnDisable()
   {
    playerControls.Disable();
    //playerControls.Player.Shoot.performed += _ => StopFiring();
   }

    void StartFiring()
    {
     fireCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RapidFire());
    }

    void StopFiring()
    {
        if(fireCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(fireCoroutine);
        }
    }

   public Vector2 GetPlayerMovement()
   {
    return playerControls.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
   }

   public Vector2 GetMouseDelta(){
    return playerControls.Player.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>();
   }

   public bool PlayerJumpedThisFrame(){
    return playerControls.Player.Jump.triggered;
   }

   public void Shooting()
   {      
        RaycastHit hit;
        //creates the bullet
        GameObject bullet = GameObject.Instantiate(bulletPrefab, barrelTransform.position, Quaternion.identity, bulletParent);
        BulletController bulletController = bullet.GetComponent<BulletController>();
        //shoots the bullet forwards
        if (Physics.Raycast(cameraTransform.position, cameraTransform.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            {   
                //checks if the bullet hit something
                bulletController.target = hit.point;
                bulletController.hit = true;
                //makes enemy take damage
                Enemy takingDamage = hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (takingDamage != null) 
            {
                takingDamage.TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        //makes enemy go backwards when hit
        if(hit.rigidbody != null)
            {
                hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * impactForce);
            }
            }
        else 
            {
                bulletController.target = cameraTransform.position + cameraTransform.forward * bulletHitMissDistance;
                bulletController.hit = false;
            }
    }
    public IEnumerator RapidFire()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Shooting();
            yield return rapidFireWait;
        }
    }

    public void Running()
    {
        /* if(playerController.currentStamina > 0){
            isRunning = true;
            staminaBar.UseStamina(playerController.staminaDrain);
            staminaBar.staminaSlider.value = playerController.currentStamina;
        } */
    isRunning = true;
    }

    public void RunningStop(){
        isRunning =false;
    }

}
```

I'm using unity new input system and tried to call the function in two different ways: in the isRunning and when I actually do the sprint function.

I was expecting the player to lose 10 stamina every time I press the sprint button, I was trying to figure that out before trying to make him lose stamina while the button is pressed.

I've seen a couple videos on YouTube, which is where I got the code from, but can't find out what I'm doing wrong when calling the function, I've had similar problems before when trying to call a TakeDamage function but I guess that's a different question.

Comment: Completely off topic but this assignment `move = new Vector3(movement.x, 0f, movement.y);` is pretty redundant ;)

Comment: Instead of a coroutine and thinking in ticks .. why not simply increase the stamina over time a bit every frame like e.g. `private void Update(){ playerController.currentStamina += playerController.maxStamina * Time.deltaTime / desiredSecondsToLoadFromZeroMax; staminaSlider.value = playerController.currentStamina; }` this should also probably rather be handled by your player controller and the healtbar just is a visualizer but not the one actively changing the value

Comment: I was using a coroutine because that's what the tutorials i was following were doing.

I tried adding that code on the void Update, but the same thing keeps happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I would do.

Instead of controlling the stamina in multiple places and hve forth and back references (=dependencies) between all your scripts I would rather keep this authority within the `PlayerController`.

Your `StaminaBar` component should be purely **listening** and visualizing the current value without having the authority to modify it.

Next step would be to decide for a general code structure

- Who is responsible for what?
- Who knows / controls what?

There are many possible answers to those but for now an this specific case

- You can either say the `PlayerController` "knows" the `StaminaBar` just like it also knows the `InputManager` and can't live without both
- Or you could decouple them and let the `PlayerController` work without having the visualization via the `StaminaBar` but rather let the `StaminaBar` listen to the value and just display it .. or not if you want to remove or change this later on

Personally I would go with the second so I will try and give you an example how I would deal with this:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Own References")]
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController _controller;

    [Header("Scene References")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform _cameraTransform;
    [SerializeField] private InputManager _inputManager;

    // In general always make you stuff as encapsulated as possible
    // -> nobody should be able to change these except you via the Inspector
    // (Values you are anyway not gonna change at all you could also convert to "const")
    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private float _maxHealth = 100f;
    [SerializeField] private float _maxStamina = 100f;
    [SerializeField] private float _staminaDrainPerSecond = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float _secondsDelayBeforeStaminaRegen = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float _staminaRegenPerSecond = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float _playerSpeed = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float _playerRunSpeed = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpHeight = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float _gravityValue = -9.81f;

    // Your runtime valus
    private float _staminaRegenDelayTimer;
    private float _currentHealt;
    private float _currentStamina;

    // You only need a single float for this
    private float _currentYVelocity;

    // EVENTS we expose so other classes can react to those
    public UnityEvent OnDeath;
    public UnityEvent<float> OnHealthChanged;
    public UnityEvent<float> OnStaminaChanged;

    // Provide public read-only access to the settings so your visuals can access those for their setup
    public float MaxHealth => _maxHealth;
    public float MaxStamina => _maxStamina;

    // And then use properties for your runtime values
    // whenever you set the value you do additional stuff like cleaning the value and invoke according events
    public float currentHealth
    {
        get => _currentHealt;
        private set
        {
            _currentHealt = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, _maxHealth);

            OnHealthChanged.Invoke(_currentHealt);

            if (value <= 0f)
            {
                OnDeath.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    public float currentStamina
    {
        get => _currentStamina;
        private set
        {
            _currentStamina = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, _maxStamina);

            OnStaminaChanged.Invoke(_currentStamina);
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        // As a thumb rule to avoid issues with order I usually initialize everything I an in Awake
        if (!_controller) _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        currentHealth = MaxHealth;
        currentStamina = MaxStamina;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // in start do the things were you depend on others already being initialized
        if (!_inputManager) _inputManager = InputManager.Instance;
        if (!_cameraTransform) _cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateStamina();

        UpdateHorizontalMovement();

        UpdateVerticalMovement();
    }

    private void UpdateStamina()
    {
        if (_inputManager.IsRunning)
        {
            // drain your stamina -> also informs all listeners
            currentStamina -= _staminaDrainPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

            // reset the regen timer
            _staminaRegenDelayTimer = _secondsDelayBeforeStaminaRegen;
        }
        else
        {
            // only if not pressing run start the regen timer
            if (_staminaRegenDelayTimer > 0)
            {
                _staminaRegenDelayTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                // once timer is finished start regen
                currentStamina += _staminaRegenPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateHorizontalMovement()
    {
        var movement = _inputManager.PlayerMovement;
        var move = _cameraTransform.forward * movement.y + _cameraTransform.right * movement.x;
        move.y = 0f;
        move *= _inputManager.IsRunning && currentStamina > 0 ? _playerRunSpeed : _playerSpeed;
        _controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void UpdateVerticalMovement()
    {
        if (_controller.isGrounded)
        {
            if (_inputManager.JumpedThisFrame)
            {
                _currentYVelocity += Mathf.Sqrt(_jumpHeight * -3.0f * _gravityValue);
            }
            else if (_currentYVelocity < 0)
            {
                _currentYVelocity = 0f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _currentYVelocity += _gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        _controller.Move(Vector3.up * _currentYVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

And then your `StaminaBar` shinks down to really only being a display. The `PlayerController` doesn't care/even know it exists and can fully work without it.

```
public class StaminaBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Slider _staminaSlider;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerController _playerController;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // or wherever you get the reference from
        if (!_playerController) _playerController = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();

        // poll the setting from the player
        _staminaSlider.maxValue = _playerController.MaxStamina;

        // attach a callback to the event 
        _playerController.OnStaminaChanged.AddListener(OnStaminaChanged);

        // just to be sure invoke the callback once immediately with the current value
        // so we don't have to wait for the first actual event invocation
        OnStaminaChanged(_playerController.currentStamina);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()  
    {
        if(_playerController) _playerController.OnStaminaChanged.RemoveListener(OnStaminaChanged);
    }

    // This will now be called whenever the stamina has changed
    private void OnStaminaChanged(float stamina)
    {
        _staminaSlider.value = stamina;
    }
}
```

And just for completeness - I also refactored your `InputManager` a bit on the fly ^^

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Own references")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform _bulletParent;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _barrelTransform;

    [Header("Scene references")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform _cameraTransform;

    // By using the correct component right away you can later skip "GetComponent"
    [Header("Assets")]
    [SerializeField] private BulletController _bulletPrefab;

    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private float _bulletHitMissDistance = 25f;
    [SerializeField] private float _damage = 100;
    [SerializeField] private float _impactForce = 30;
    [SerializeField] private float _fireRate = 8f;

    public static InputManager Instance { get; private set; }

    // Again I would use properties here
    // You don't want anything else to set the "isRunning" flag
    // And the others don't need to be methods either
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }
    public Vector2 PlayerMovement => _playerControls.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    public Vector2 MouseDelta => _playerControls.Player.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    public bool JumpedThisFrame => _playerControls.Player.Jump.triggered;

    private Coroutine _fireCoroutine;
    private PlayerControls _playerControls;
    private WaitForSeconds _rapidFireWait;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
        }

        _playerControls = new PlayerControls();

        //Cursor.visible = false;

        _rapidFireWait = new WaitForSeconds(1 / _fireRate);
        _cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

        _playerControls.Player.RunStart.performed += _ => Running();
        _playerControls.Player.RunEnd.performed += _ => RunningStop();
        _playerControls.Player.Shoot.started += _ => StartFiring();
        _playerControls.Player.Shoot.canceled += _ => StopFiring();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _playerControls.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _playerControls.Disable();
    }

    private void StartFiring()
    {
        _fireCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RapidFire());
    }

    private void StopFiring()
    {
        if (_fireCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(_fireCoroutine);
            _fireCoroutine = null;
        }
    }

    private void Shooting()
    {
        var bulletController = Instantiate(_bulletPrefab, _barrelTransform.position, Quaternion.identity, _bulletParent);

        if (Physics.Raycast(_cameraTransform.position, _cameraTransform.forward, out var hit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            bulletController.target = hit.point;
            bulletController.hit = true;

            if (hit.transform.TryGetComponent<Enemy>(out var enemy))
            {
                enemy.TakeDamage(_damage);
            }

            if (hit.rigidbody != null)
            {
                hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * _impactForce);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bulletController.target = _cameraTransform.position + _cameraTransform.forward * _bulletHitMissDistance;
            bulletController.hit = false;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator RapidFire()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Shooting();
            yield return _rapidFireWait;
        }
    }

    private void Running()
    {
        IsRunning = true;
    }

    private void RunningStop()
    {
        IsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!
I'm not sure i understand all that you changed but i'll take a look into it, i hadn't seen those unity events yet so i'm not sure how they work.
I have a question tho, if i were to make the player take damage now, would i just call the currentHealth function?

Answer (score -1):

You're decreasing and increasing the stamina in the same scope. I think you should let the stamina to be drained when sprint is pressed and start regenerating only if it is released.